# node-webkit app not working on windows 7 32 bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, nwjs

i am new in node webkit and developing desktop application in html. i have create a small project and run using nw.exe and its working fine in windows 8.1 64 bit but its not working in windows 7.

Means it run if i click many times then suddenly start and after close once then not able to run again.

My **package.json**

```
{
"window": {
"icon": "app.png",
"toolbar": true,
"show": false,
"toolbar": false,
"frame": true,
"position": "center",
"width": 1360,
"height": 720
},
"apache_port": 81,
"mysql_port": 3308,
"name": "My App",
"version": "1.0.0",
"author": "Author",
"email": "test@yahoo.com",
"phone": "+91-9999999999",
"url": "http://example.com",
"main": "index.html"
```

}

**Index.html**

```
<script>
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
var target = this;
return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};

var gui = require("nw.gui");

var fs = require('fs');

if(process.env.PWD) {
    process.chdir(process.env.PWD);
}

/**
* Base dirpath
*/
var base_path=process.cwd();

var i=0;
while(i!=-1) {
base_path=base_path.replace("\\","/");
i=base_path.indexOf('\\');
}

/**
* Package.JSON Details
*/
var package;

//read config file
fs.readFile('./package.json', 'utf-8', function (error, contents) {
    package = JSON.parse(contents);
});

function log(str) { 
    //document.getElementById('text').value+= (str+"\n");
}

function proc_config(file,path) {
    fs.readFile(base_path+'/config/'+file, 'utf-8', function (error, contents) {

        var substr="%phpbrowserbox%";
        var replc=base_path;
        contents = contents.replaceAll(substr, replc);

        contents = contents.replaceAll('%mysql_port%', package.mysql_port);
        contents = contents.replaceAll('%apache_port%', package.apache_port);


        fs.writeFile(base_path+"/"+path+"/"+file, contents, function(err) {
        if(err) {
                return log("error:"+err);
        }


        log(file+" was saved to "+base_path+"/"+path+"/"+file);
    }); 


    });

}
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Please wait...</title>
<style>
html,body {height:100%;}
</style>

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;">

<img src="splash.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;">

<script>
 window.onload=function() { 
 document.title=package.name;
 proc_config('php.ini','bin/php');
 proc_config('php.ini','bin/apache/bin');

 proc_config('my.ini','bin/mysql');
 proc_config('httpd.conf','bin/apache/conf');

 var mysqld=base_path+"/bin/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe"
 var httpd=base_path+"/bin/apache/bin/httpd.exe"

 var proc = require('child_process');

//start apache server
proc.spawn(httpd);

//start mysql server
proc.spawn(mysqld);

location.href="http://localhost:"+package.apache_port+"?apache_port="+package.apache_port+"&mysql_port="+package.mysql_port+"&cache="+Math.random()+"&base_path="+base_path;

gui.Window.get().show();
} 
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

can any one help ?

Comment: are you using a 32 bit version of nw.js?

Comment: actually i am using phpbrowser box and its in node webkit so i don't know exact what version they are using !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 64bit NW won't work on 32bit systems but the 32bit should work on all systems. To save yourself a lot of hassle just compile and stick with the 32bit.
64bit apps are always slower anyway because the memory addressing mode is double in size and every instruction (large or small) has to clear/set/read the wider registers regardless.

Also, whenever your app runs the first time and then no longer runs, it's usually because it is still in memory and hasn't fully/properly exited. To check this do a CTRL+ALT+DEL and kill the processes if still there.

Finally, your PACKAGE.JSON seems a little lacking so consider researching and adding some more parameters like...

```
     "nodejs": true,
```

"single-instance": true,
"page-cache" : false

...and so forth. Good luck.